# Active Record. Making a "Visit" counter with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I currently have a `Check_In` model that **belongs_to** my `Subscriber` model which **has_many** `Check_Ins`.

The `Subscriber` model takes in a phone_number along with some other attributes and the `Check_In` model take in a "visit_amount" as an integer.

After a person `Subscribes` with the view form I want the option for them to `Check_In` by placing their `subscriber` phone_number in a `Check_In` view form.

After they place their number in the form the `Check_In` model will + 1 to the "visit_amount" on that particular `Subscriber`.

I'm new to rails and I'm wondering if this is possible? if so, how should I go about implementing this feature? I will show my current code for reference.

MODEL

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :check_ins

 validates :first_name, presence: true
 validates :last_name, presence: true
 validates :email, presence: true
 validates :phone_number, presence: true

 def date_joined
  created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
 end

 def expiration_date
  (created_at + 1.year).strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
 end
end
```

~

```
class Check_In < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :subscriber
end
```

I have basic controllers and views. Everything is really basic at this point but this is the main feature that I need for this app.

Comment: Easily doable, answering from my phone so need some time to type it lol

Comment: Thanks! appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the create action for your use case.

```
class CheckInsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # First, create a CheckIn that belongs to the current_subscriber
    @check_in = CheckIn.new.tap do |check_in|
      check_in.subscriber = current_subscriber
    end

    # Then check if submitted phone number is correct
    if params[:phone_number] == current_subscriber.phone_number
      @check_in.save
    else
      # do something when the verification failed
    end
  end

  # more code...
end
```

Hope that helps.

If you do not have authentication in the app, you can do

```
def create
   subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number])
   if subscriber
     CheckIn.create(subscriber: subscriber)
   else
     # some code
   end
 end
```

Last, your form should look like :

```
<%= form_tag check_ins_path do %>
  <%= label :phone_number %>
  <%= text_field_tag :phone_number %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Check In' %>
<% end %>
```

Do not use `form_for @check_in` or your params will look like `{ check_in: { phone_number: '1234-56-7890' }` and you will have to fetch `params[:check_in][:phone_number]` in your create action, which feels uncomfortable to me(check ins do not have phone numbers).

Comment: This helps for sure. The only problem is I don't think their will be a current_user. basically I want to make an sql query that says, if number that was typed in exists? add 1 to counter for that particular number. if that makes sense?

Comment: use the second solution, and give a try to `counter_cache`.

Comment: Thank you. one last question what should my form look like for the view? what if the text_field for?

Answer (score 1):

:counter_cache can do what you want. add a new field call count_of_check_ins in the table subscribers, then update the class definition as follow:

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins
end

class Check_In < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber, counter_cache: :count_of_check_ins
end
```

the count_of_check_ins will be updated automatically.

Comment: It's important for my case that it only counts if the user types in their phone number. will this work for that my situation?

Comment: I like what you're thinking. I guess I'm just curious if you can elaborate?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a simple declaration can do that trick. For your case, I would suggest that you add an after_update and after_destroy callback inside the Check_In model, and do the calculation your self.

Answer (score 1):

On the page where you want the form to accept the users input for a checkin put the following in its corresponding action (typically would be the `CheckinsController`, `new` action):

```
def new
  @checkin = Check_In.new
end

def create
  user = current_user #assuming u have a current user method
  @checkin = user.check_in.new(checkin_params)
  if @checkin.save
    # ...
  end
end

private

def checkin_params
  params.require(:check_in).permit(:phone_number)
end
```

Then in your model `CheckIn` you need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` so it allows the phone number to be added.